# How to do coldfusion mapping in application level

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, mapping, coldfusion-10

I have below directory structure -

- rootFolder
- ---CFC (contains all cfc file)
- ---SERVICES (contains all service file)
- application.cfc

I have created one service named (userService.cfc) which have the below script

```
import services.userService;

component accessors="true" alias="services.userService"
{
    remote userService function init()
    {
        return This;
    }

    remote any function getUser()
{
   var userObj = new cfc.sessionUser();  

          return userObj;        
}
}
```

If i call this service from inside the application, **this is working fine**

Again if i am trying to call it from outside the application, need to change this statement as below and **again it is working fine.**

```
 import rootFolderName.services.userService;

    component accessors="true" alias="rootFolderName.services.userService"
    {
        remote userServicefunction init()
        {
            return This;
        }

            remote any function getUser()
        {
             var userObj = new rootFolderName.cfc.sessionUser();  

                return userObj;        
         }
    }
```

But If i put this code on another rootFolder suppose on "rootFolderName1"  name i have to changed all the place where i used the rootFolderName. I got one solution by CFADMIN folder mapping on server level. but i want it on application level.

Can we configure it on Application.cfc? I have used Mappings also but that is not working.

**Actually i have two separate application one flex application which is trying to access the second  application services remotely. second application have cfc and sevices.**

Please help on this.

Comment: What have you placed in your this.mappings variables? You should be able to set the mappings in each application to point to your root services folder.

Answer (score 3):

I would review Ben Nadel's post on the use of ExpandPath() in writing app level CF mappings

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2519-ExpandPath-Works-With-ColdFusion-s-Per-Application-Mappings.htm

Comment: I have updated my question, Please review once and let me know if their any possibility.

Comment: The bits that Ben mentions in his article should still apply, for the per application mappings, and should be exactly what you require to get straightened out.